# Sonar lint reports null possible point exception

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

Sonar lint reports possible null point exception on Java code snippet below inside the for loop:
         for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
.
.}

Any ide how to solve the issue please?
Here is the method:

```
private ArrayList<String> listFileNamesInFolder(final File folder) {

    ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    ArrayList<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

     for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        assertNotNull(fileEntry);
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {                        
            listFileNamesInFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            if(fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".csv")) {
                fileList.add(fileEntry);
                fileNameList.add(fileEntry.getName());
                setTestInfo(fileEntry.getName());                    
            }
        }
    }
    return fileNameList;
}
```

Comment: Which version of SonarLint do you use? Where precisely is the issue reported?

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc for `listFiles` in `File` says that it returns:

> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

Because this can return `null`, you may want to check for this value before iterating over the array to prevent a `NullPointerException` like:

```
File[] fileEntries = folder.listFiles();
if (fileEntries == null) {
    // ...
} else {
    for (final File fileEntry : fileEntries) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When `fileEntries` is `null`, you can choose to either throw an exception, or return an empty list.

Comment: Did help. Thanks

Comment: File[] fileEntries = folder.listFiles();
        assertNotNull(fileEntries);
            for (File fileEntry : fileEntries) {..... }